# Image Processing : Border detection of an object on (quite) the same background color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, edge-detection

I'm working on Python 3.6, with almost only OpenCV.3.
I'm trying to find automatically the contours of a sheet of paper to crop it at the right size, here is on example :

[image]

I've seen a lot of posts about quite the same subject but finally nothing really for me.

So this is the code I use:

```
orig = cv2.imread("Image.jpg")
cv2.imshow('result', imutils.resize(orig, height=600))
cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0, img)


edges = cv2.Canny(img,10,20,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imshow('result', imutils.resize(edges, height=600))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And this is the output:

[image: canny]

So now I try to find the countours Using HougLines or the HougLinesProbabilities.

```
#minLineLength=100000
#maxLineGap=50
#lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180*10,150,0,0)
```

But I don't have anything usable.. (I would be able to add what I obtain if I have more reputation here)
I don't know if I don't have to use HoughLines or if I just can't get the right parameters..
I've already looked at corner detection but it's quite the same problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is what you are lookign for a rectangle? try to find the biggest rectangle (in 3D) in your canny image, that will get the paper. Sidenote: as seen by my suggestion, image processing solutions are often very problem specific. If a white piece of paper with nice words for SO is not your common case, you should try to add the real one

Comment: it's gonna be expends, so kind of the same. still rectangle, still white, and so on. I've tried to find the biggest rectangle, but most of the case it's not working because the total rectangle is not complete, there is most of the time one half of one side missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are more different than you think.

Flatten the luminance of the image to correct the illumination artifacts, then keep the pixels closer to the color of the sheet than that of the background.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if may elaborate a little more, in terms of theory and code!

Comment: @ShreyanshDwivedi: sorry, I am not a free coding factory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found something pretty nice, for the ones who will arrived on this page.

First, find all contours, and out them on a blackpicture. (I have drawn them bigger, like that you are not bothered if there is space between the contours OpenCv find)

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours=list(filter(lambda cont: cv2.arcLength(cont, False) > 60, contours))
# show only contours
blank = np.zeros((orig.shape[0],orig.shape[1],3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(blank, contours,-1,(0,255,0),5)
```

[contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xlVq.png)

```
edges = cv2.Canny(blank,10,20,apertureSize = 3)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

And apply canny & find contour a second time. This step is really just to be able to find a real contour if your image is not perfect.

```
maxcontour=0
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img, cnt, 0, (255, 255, 0), 2)
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>5000:  # remove small areas like noise etc
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)    # find the convex hull of contour
        hull = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull,0.1*cv2.arcLength(hull,True),True)
        if len(hull)==4:
            cv2.drawContours(img,[hull],0,(0,255,0),2)
```

[final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaXKW.png)